# Add to Slack hyperlink takes me to https://dev.botframework.com/ instead of slack app

Tags: azure, botframework, slack

I have configured a bot in azure portal and added Slack as a channel. And, I have configured the slack channel details such as Client ID, Secret, Signing Secret, Scopes and the various URLs. Please see the picture below.

[image: slack credentials in azure bot]

Now when I use the link (Add to slack), after giving the permission to access my slack workspace, I am taken to https://dev.botframework.com/. I would rather expect to be taken to either the slack web app or the slack desktop app. What am I missing to configure/do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In interactive components we need to give a "Request URL"

Check whether it was mentioned as:

https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions

If this doesn't work as per requirement. Kindly re-generate Secret ID and Verification Token and check with the landing URL.

There is no restriction to use either Slack web app or desktop app. It can work on both if the landing page and app setup was done perfectly. Once regenerate the Client secret ID and Verification Token.

Comment: Thank @SairamTadepelli-MT. I dont require interactive components configuration. However, I tried what you have mentioned (Request URL) and it didnt work. I created a  brand new slack app too. It did not work either.